# stop javascript countdown function if condition

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout, decrement

I have a function that displays a count down clock according to a variable. What would be the right way to stop it in the specified condition? clearTimeout is not stoping the Decrement functions.

```
function interface_vip(type){
    var timeout = '';
    var clock = '';
    //display clock
    function Decrement() {
        currentMinutes = Math.floor(secs / 60);
        currentSeconds = secs % 60;
        if(currentSeconds <= 9) currentSeconds = "0" + currentSeconds;
            secs--;
            if(secs !== -1) timeout = setTimeout(Decrement,1000);
    }
    if (type == 1){
        var mins = 20;
        var secs = mins * 60;
        var currentSeconds = 0;
        var currentMinutes = 0;
        clock = setTimeout(Decrement,1000);
    }
    if (type == 2){
        clearTimeout(clock);
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
}
```

Comment: you have an error, t is not defined

Comment: look that `interface` is a reserved word in JavaScript https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/reserved-keywords#ecmascript-2

Comment: variable t is defined in my js, I'll changed it to a number in my question, it's working

Comment: @Lionel T right, changed in my question I used this word translated in the original code and did not realize it when did the question.

Comment: great, for the rest I don't understand at all the question, could you post a working (or at least trying to) snippet/fiddle/pen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your clock id is lost at the second call ,a poor solution is to create the variables global

```
    var timeout = '';
        var clock = '';
  function interface_vip(type){   
        //display clock
        function Decrement() {
            currentMinutes = Math.floor(secs / 60);
            currentSeconds = secs % 60;
            if(currentSeconds <= 9) currentSeconds = "0" + currentSeconds;
                secs--;
                if(secs !== -1) timeout = setTimeout(Decrement,1000);
        }
        if (type == 1){
            var mins = 20;
            var secs = mins * 60;
            var currentSeconds = 0;
            var currentMinutes = 0;
            clock = setTimeout(Decrement,1000);
        }
        if (type == 2){
            clearTimeout(clock);
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        }
    }
```

a better approach in the bellow snippet

```js
function interface_vip(){
    var timeout = '';
    var t = 0;
    var clock = '';
    //display clock
    function Decrement() {
        currentMinutes = Math.floor(secs / 60);
        currentSeconds = secs % 60;
        if(currentSeconds <= 9) currentSeconds = "0" + currentSeconds;
            secs--;
            if(secs !== -1) timeout = setTimeout(Decrement,1000);
    }
   this.start = function(){
        var mins = t;
        var secs = mins * 60;
        var currentSeconds = 0;
        var currentMinutes = 0;
        clock = setTimeout(Decrement,1000);
    }
    this.stop = function(){
        clearTimeout(clock);
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
}
var interf = new interface_vip();
interf.start();
interf.stop();
```

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't see it. That solves the problem :D

Comment: I've added a better solution in the answer